# ftp permissions for creating directory with proftpd on vfat usb on Pi3

Tags: linux, usb, permissions, ftp, vfat

I have a usb drive attached to my Pi3 with vfat filesystem.  I've mounted it in fstab and assigned a uid and gid.  I am using pfoftpd to allow storage of files and allow directories to be created.  I have several users like user1, user2, etc. I can ssh in and create directories with any of these users.  However using ftp I can only create a directory with whichever user I make as uid in fstab.  The gid seems to make no difference, no other user can create a directory on this vfat usb.  Is there a way to make the entire group be able to create directories, they all can upload files to that directory for some reason though.

**Here is my fs tab:**

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
/dev/sda1       /media/usbhdd   vfat  auto,nofail,noatime,users,umask=000,uid=camera,gid=ftpusb     0       0
```

**Here are my users that are relevant:**

```
proftpd:x:112:65534::/run/proftpd:/bin/false
ftp:x:113:65534::/srv/ftp:/bin/false
amcrest:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/amcrest:/bin/bash
userftp:x:1002:1002::/home/FTP-shared:/bin/false
camera:x:1003:1003::/media/usbhdd/cam1:/bin/bash
cam1:x:1004:1005:cam1,,,:/media/usbhdd/cam1:/bin/bash
dnsmasq:x:114:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
```

**Here is my permissions for the usb drive:**

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 camera ftpusb      16384 Dec 16  2015 System Volume Information
drwxrwxrwx  2 camera ftpusb      16384 Oct 21 09:14 test1
drwxrwxrwx  2 camera ftpusb      16384 Oct 27 06:45 test2
drwxrwxrwx  2 camera ftpusb      16384 Oct 27 08:33 test3
drwxrwxrwx  2 camera ftpusb      16384 Nov  7 08:56 test4
```

**Here is my proftp conf file:**

```
#
# /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf -- This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file.
# To really apply changes, reload proftpd after modifications, if
# it runs in daemon mode. It is not required in inetd/xinetd mode.
#

# Includes DSO modules
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

# Set off to disable IPv6 support which is annoying on IPv4 only boxes.
UseIPv6                         off # !!!!!!!!!!!!!1I changed to off
# If set on you can experience a longer connection delay in many cases.
IdentLookups                    off

ServerName                      "Debian"
ServerType                      standalone
DeferWelcome                    off

MultilineRFC2228                on
DefaultServer                   on
ShowSymlinks                    on

TimeoutNoTransfer               600
TimeoutStalled                  600
TimeoutIdle                     1200

DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir                    .message true
ListOptions                     "-l"

DenyFilter                      \*.*/

# Use this to jail all users in their homes
# DefaultRoot                   ~

# Users require a valid shell listed in /etc/shells to login.
# Use this directive to release that constrain.
# RequireValidShell             off

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                            21

# In some cases you have to specify passive ports range to by-pass
# firewall limitations. Ephemeral ports can be used for that, but
# feel free to use a more narrow range.
# PassivePorts                  49152 65534

# If your host was NATted, this option is useful in order to
# allow passive tranfers to work. You have to use your public
# address and opening the passive ports used on your firewall as well.
# MasqueradeAddress             1.2.3.4

# This is useful for masquerading address with dynamic IPs:
# refresh any configured MasqueradeAddress directives every 8 hours
<IfModule mod_dynmasq.c>
# DynMasqRefresh 28800
</IfModule>

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances                    30

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User                            proftpd
Group                           nogroup

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
# (second parm) from being group and world writable.
#Umask                          022  022  #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!I got rid of this to see if it would work for group
# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
AllowOverwrite                  on

# Uncomment this if you are using NIS or LDAP via NSS to retrieve passwords:
# PersistentPasswd              off

# This is required to use both PAM-based authentication and local passwords
# AuthOrder                     mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c

# Be warned: use of this directive impacts CPU average load!
# Uncomment this if you like to see progress and transfer rate with ftpwho
# in downloads. That is not needed for uploads rates.
#
# UseSendFile                   off

TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
ExtendedLog /var/log/proftpd/extendlog.log

# Logging onto /var/log/lastlog is enabled but set to off by default
#UseLastlog on

# In order to keep log file dates consistent after chroot, use timezone info
# from /etc/localtime.  If this is not set, and proftpd is configured to
# chroot (e.g. DefaultRoot or <Anonymous>), it will use the non-daylight
# savings timezone regardless of whether DST is in effect.
#SetEnv TZ :/etc/localtime

<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
QuotaEngine off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
</IfModule>


# Delay engine reduces impact of the so-called Timing Attack described in
# http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/11430/discuss
# It is on by default.
<IfModule mod_delay.c>
DelayEngine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
ControlsEngine        off
ControlsMaxClients    2
ControlsLog           /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
ControlsInterval      5
ControlsSocket        /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
AdminControlsEngine off
</IfModule>

#
# Alternative authentication frameworks
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/ldap.conf
#Include /etc/proftpd/sql.conf

#
# This is used for FTPS connections
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/tls.conf

#
# Useful to keep VirtualHost/VirtualRoot directives separated
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/virtuals.conf

# A basic anonymous configuration, no upload directories.

# <Anonymous ~ftp>
#   User                                ftp
#   Group                               nogroup
#   # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
#   UserAlias                   anonymous ftp
#   # Cosmetic changes, all files belongs to ftp user
#   DirFakeUser on ftp
#   DirFakeGroup on ftp
#
#   RequireValidShell           off
#
#   # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
#   MaxClients                  10
#
#   # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, and '.message' displayed
#   # in each newly chdired directory.
#   DisplayLogin                        welcome.msg
#   DisplayChdir                .message
#
#   # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
#   <Directory *>
#     <Limit WRITE>
#       DenyAll
#     </Limit>
#   </Directory>
#
#   # Uncomment this if you're brave.
#   # <Directory incoming>
#   #   # Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
#   #   # (second parm) from being group and world writable.
#   #     Umask                  022   022
#   #            <Limit READ WRITE>
#   #            DenyAll
#   #            </Limit>
#   #            <Limit STOR>
#   #            AllowAll
#   #            </Limit>
#   # </Directory>
<Directory /media/usbhdd>
Umask 000 000
AllowOverwrite on
    <Limit READ>
        DenyAll
        </Limit>

        <Limit STOR CWD MKD RMD DELE XRMD XMKD RETR>
        AllowAll
        </Limit>

        <Limit WRITE>
        AllowUser camera
        AllowUser cam1
        </Limit>
</Directory>
#
# </Anonymous>

# Include other custom configuration files
Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/

DefaultRoot ~
AuthOrder mod_auth_file.c  mod_auth_unix.c
AuthUserFile /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
AuthPAM off
RequireValidShell off
```